# Is it OK to invite PhD scientists (Bio and Pharma) to peer review manuscripts?

Tags: peer-review

I recently joined the editorial board of a decent OA journal. I got requests to handle quite some manuscripts very soon.

I accepted to handle the first 2 and soon I saw another two and then another 2. So I got invitation for 6 manuscripts within a week and they are still coming.

I am a 5th year AP and don't have much time to handle all of them. So I need to make some decisions.

Finally I decided to handle at most 5 on my hands at the same time.

This is my first time being on editor board and I need lots of input. What's your suggestions?

The other question is that I was thinking about inviting some PhD scientists (Bio and Pharma) as the reviewers because I met them in related meetings and I think they could do some fair reviews. Would that be OK in general?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: There are two questions here, and the first one seems very broad. Please, keep it to one question per post, it works best in this format. Feel free to add new questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation here.  Why wouldn't it be OK to invite PhD scientists to peer review manuscripts?  As an editor, one of your main jobs is arranging peer review, and you can ask just about anyone who is qualified and impartial.  What is it about these scientists that makes you wonder whether they would be appropriate reviewers?